# both dialog and popups showing as divs at bottom of page

Tags: google-apps-script

GAS has all these controls for the dialog boxes and popups.  I know in GWT they work great, but in GAS, they are simply showing up as div's with a pretty blue border around them at the bottom of the page.

am i supposed to import a styelsheet that i don't know about or something?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably adding them to your app in your code. **Don't do this.**
Simply create the dialog box and call .show() or .hide() on it as needed.